# Make table sortable in Wordpress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a table to show data related to my plugin in wordpress admin.

```
<th scope="col" id="title" class="manage-column column-title sortable desc" style="">
<a href="<?php echo  get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Webinar_Reg/allmenu.php&amp;orderby=title&amp;order=asc">
<span>Title</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></a></th>
```

But, when I click on column header(Title) the page refreshes without the title column getting sorted.

I used this link for reference http://pippinsplugins.com/creating-wp-list-tables-by-hand/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery plugin [TableSorter](http://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/) - it is client-side table sorting without need to refresh the page, very flexible and powerful, refresh-less table sort will provide better user experience.

See the [demo](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki).

EDIT: In order to use native Wordpress sorting, your table column must have CSS class `sorted`, when you want it to be sorted (according your reference link):

```
<th class="manage-column column-title sortable sorted">
  <a href="add_query_args_here">Sortable (and currently sorted)</a>
</th>
```

Comment: I know, but for this case I need ti use native wordpress methods and styles